# Why does my CSS not work with a different file name?

Tags: css, cloudflare

I have been using a central CSS file to build my site and have added to and modified it over time. I use cloudflare which caches CSS files every few hours, so to avoid this I change the number on the end of the file name each time and update it in my header template. This worked fine for months on two different servers.

But just recently it has decided not to allow this. If I change the CSS's file name and reference link, the CSS will not load. If I set it back to what it was before (site_main61.css) then it works just fine. I've even tried using different characters than increment numbers at the end and still end up with the same result.

This started happening out of the blue; no changes had been made to the server. Could this be a problem with Cloudflare? Something else?

I can provide more details if needed, but I can't think of anything that would be relevant right now.

The problem is not related to forgetting to update the link in html. I've tested this countless times to be sure.

Comment: This is like a needle in a haystack. Since it's working with your old file name, I would say to start at cloudflare. Or maybe you should check your CSS to see if there's any missing characters or something that would break the compiler?

Comment: My guess is you're probably missing a step. When you rename your css file on the server to site_main62.css perhaps you're forgetting to change the link in your HTML?

Comment: I've run the CSS through the W3C CSS validation checker and it shows no issues. I thought of this as well, so I tried renaming the file without changing any of the code. Unfortunately I got the same result. I know it's a tricky problem to figure out, but I like to ask here in case there's some quirky thing I'm missing.

Comment: I update the html link every time I change the file name.

Comment: If you host it outside of cloudflare (e.g. on your web server) does it work?

Comment: Cloudflare does not host content in the way you seem to think. They have servers all over the world that that act like proxies to your server, and cache some of the static files on it. All the source files come directly from my webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a query string the to end of the file name. It will be cached as a separate file, but it will be the same filename. It's basically a forced recache for the file. Just go to the link in the HTML and add something like this:

```
<link href="path/to/file/site_main61.css?version=1" ... />
```

This will work with most caching systems and you no longer have to change the file name.

Comment: I'm still unsure why my old method stopped working, but I've tried your suggestion and it's working perfectly. Thanks very much for the suggestion :)